# Multimedia search engine with low footprint

Tags: open-source, web-apps, search-engine, document-indexing

I'd like to build a searchable index for some non-public servers, hosting the software myself. Typical choices seem to be YaCy, Lucene or its descendants Solr and ElasticSearch, but I don't want a Java solution (mostly for performance, but also opsec reasons).

Requirements:

- FOSS
- low resource footprint
- multimedia metadata indexing (ID3, ogg tags etc.)
- [Bonus] local indexing proxy, i.e. the server hosting the media extracts metadata, instead of the indexer fetching each media file to read its tags
- website for querying

Maybe related: [Intranet crawler and search engine](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/955/intranet-crawler-and-search-engine)