# Intranet Search Engine

Tags: search-engine

In our company we have several sources of information:

- github (private repos). Docs in mark-down files.
- Jira Issues
- Confluence (Wiki like tool)
- Stack Overflow for Teams
- Articles in [Staffbase](https://staffbase.com/en/)

Some teams prefer this tool, the other teams prefer that tool.

You can't force them to use only one tool.

I would like to have a intranet search engine which can provide results from several places.

Open source is preferred, but a commercial tools is ok.

SaaS is not allowed, it must run on-premise.

I wrote some more details here: [intranet-search-cockpit (github)](https://github.com/guettli/intranet-search-cockpit/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intranet crawler and search engine](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/955/intranet-crawler-and-search-engine)

Comment: @browly to other question you linked to searches for a free solution. For me a good commercial software works, too.